# Query inside model, how to get numer of items in specific class

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I've come up with this:

```
[NotMapped]
    public int ThreadsInBoard
    {
        get
        {
            ForumContextContainer ctx = new ForumContextContainer();
            int thr = (from p in ctx.BoardSet
                       from x in ctx.ThreadSet
                       where p.BoardID == x.Board.BoardID
                       select p).Count();
        }
    }
```

What I want to do is the count of threads, that are in the specific board.
This query actually return count of every possible thread in database and assign it.
Below are involved classes

```
    public partial class Board
{
    public int BoardID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisibleToGuests { get; set; }
    public bool IsLocked { get; set; }

    public Forum Forum { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Thread> Thread { get; set; }
}

    public partial class Thread
{
    public int ThreadID { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Post { get; set; }
    public Board Board { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Subscription> Subscription { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Poll> Poll { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[NotMapped]
    public int ThreadsInBoard
    {
        get
        {
            ForumContextContainer ctx = new ForumContextContainer();
            int thr = ctx.ThreadSet.Count(p => p.BoardID == this.BoardID);
        }
    }
```

assuming this class has the boardId property

Comment: Working. Need small modification p.BoardID to p.Board.BoardID, but not a big deal.